# mongoose comments and replies schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am following this link to understand how to design my schema for a social media type  module with comments and replies. https://www.xuchao.org/docs/mongodb/use-cases/storing-comments.html#gsc.tab=0 (This is for mongdb and not mongoose)

I am trying to create a schema like this

```
const socialSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Entry_Number: Number,
    Player_Name: String,
    Player_Message : String,
    Player_Fullmessage: String,
    Player_ProfilePic : String,
    Player_UploadedPic: String,
    Player_UploadedVideos: String,
    Status_Date: String,
    Status_Feeling: String,
    Google_Profile: String,
    Status_Likes: [{Like_Number: Number, Liked_By: String}],
  Status_Comments: [
                      {Comment_Number: Number,
                       Comment_By: String,
                       Comment_Message: String},
                       replies: [
                         {Comment_By: String,
                          Comment_Message: String}
                        ],
                     ],
Friends: { type: Array, default: []},
    Shares: { type: Array, default: []},
    Shared_Post: String,
    Shared_Newmessage: String,
    Shared_PostDetails: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "socialdatas"}]
```

The problem I am facing is with the replies. My logic tells me that the replies should be a array within the main comments array. However the cods as it is above, gives me an error while compiling. SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

Am I approaching this correctly? Any experts that can give me some advice. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest create a separate schemas for `comments` and `players`, then you can just use `populate()` to access data between collections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest create a separate schemas for `comments` and `players`, then you can just use `populate()` to access data between collections.

but to fix your issue above, it should be like this:

```
Status_Comments: [{
                     Comment_Number: Number,
                     Comment_By: String,
                     Comment_Message: String,
                     replies: [
                        {Comment_By: String,
                         Comment_Message: String}
                        ]
                  }]
```

Comment: sorry dude my bad,,,forgot to remove a bracket,,seems to be working now..thanks a ton

Comment: hey Karl, whats the query to update the replies array. I have tried a few combinations but nothing seems to work..can you help or at least point me in the right direction

Comment: @SandeepNair like update 1 item in the array? push into array or pull ?